# Nuances between するする vs すらすら

Tags: word-choice, onomatopoeia

Here is a question from 新完全マスターN1:語彙.

> 彼女は筆を持つと、( )と自分の名前を書いた。

The answer is すらすら, but するする is also an option.

The brief definition of するする is 「滑るように」which I take to mean in this context as a "gliding, smooth motion". I've also looked up するする in some dictionaries like Jisho and Weblio, which seem to match this definition. However, I don't understand why it is not a suitable option in this sentence.

Comment: FYI: One case するする is the preferred choice is [棒状、帯状のものが勢いよく伸びるさまを表わす](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-544065).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, onomatopoeic and mimetic words are things you have to learn by rote. Many of them are used only in a certain type of context. Most native speakers would say すらすら(と) or さらさら(と) is the most natural adverb to describe smoothness of writing characters on paper.

- すらすら is used to describe how smoothly a person writes, reads, says, recalls or calculates something.
- するする is used to describe how smoothly something moves without noise or friction. For example, a skater on ice.

Please use a modern corpus like [BCCWJ](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/en/index.html) to find more examples. (Corpora containing old text like 用例.jp can be misleading.)

Although するする(と) is not bad as an uncommon alternative in your context, it's not an appropriate choice at least in examinations.